# Scroll bar in grid column data using extjs 3

Tags: php, extjs3

I'm using extjs3 and PHP to develop an application and it's a custom framework.
I'm having grids to list records from any particular table. But if any column/field in the grid has quite a large text ex: "notes" field with a text like "my name is xyz and i'm from abc. My DOB is bla bla bla", then in this case it appears as "my name is ......" and to see the rest of the text I have to stretch that column and which is very irritating. That's why I was thinking of adding some scroll bar to that field in the grid. Please let me know if you have any alternate solutions for this case or how to use the scroll bar here.
This is ExtJs 3.4 and PHP.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css

```
.ext-strict .x-grid3-cell-inner, .ext-strict .x-grid3-hd-inner { 
   white-space:normal !important; 
 }
```